# Как мне сделать чтоб переменая а тоже увеличивалась?

Tags: c++, c

[image: Задание на фото]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = 2.0;
    float y;
    float x = 1.0;

    for (; x < 8; x += 0.5)
    {
        while (a < 10)
        {
            a++;
        }

        if (a > x)
        {
            float y = pow(a, 2) + x;
            printf("y=%f a=%f\t x=%f \n", y, a, x);
        }
        else if (a == x)
        {
            float y = a * a;
            printf("y=%f a=%f\t x=%f \n", y, a, x);
        }
        else if (a < x)
        {
            float y = (a * a) - x;
            printf("y=%f a=%f x=%f \n", y, a, x);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что Вы пытаетесь сделать - то обычным вложенным циклом.

Comment: вот ссилка на онлайн компилятор https://onlinegdb.com/Hyke9OZtD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я немного изменю Ваш код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float y;

    for (float x = 1.0; x <= 8; x += 0.5)
    {
        for (float a = 2.0; a <= 10; a +=1)
        {
            if (a > x)
            {
                float y = pow(a, 2) + x;
                printf("y=%f a=%f\t x=%f \n", y, a, x);
            }
            else if (a == x)
            {
                float y = a * a;
                printf("y=%f a=%f\t x=%f \n", y, a, x);
            }
            else if (a < x)
            {
                float y = (a * a) - x;
                printf("y=%f a=%f x=%f \n", y, a, x);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Что я сделал:

1. убрал объявления `x`, `a` в заголовки циклов. НЕ обязательное изменение.
2. Заменил `while`, который здесь не удобен, на `for`, и убрал все вычисления в тело этого нового цикла.
3. Присвоение `a=2.0` в заголовке цикла гарантирует, что для каждого `x` параметр `a` будет проходить, как и положено, весь свой диапазон.

UPD.
То, как написано у Вас по ссылке в онлайн-компиляторе работать нормально не будет, так как переменная `a` единожды (при первом проходе внешнего цикла) дойдет до 10, а после этого, на следующих проходах она при начале цикла `while` уже будет >10, и цикл выполняться не будет.